# Stop a VBS Script filling up temp Internet files

Tags: windows, vbscript, scheduled-tasks, batch-processing, temporary-files

I have a .vbs script that is creating a lot of temp Internet files fast. How can I reduce this? Its a Windows Server 2016 box

I have tried placing a limit on this using IE > Tools > temp Intranet files.... however this does not work. I suspect its because the actual browser is not being opened. The .vbs file is triggered by a Windows Scheduled Task on the hour. Its connects to an XML source using the HTTP protocol like so:

```
Set objxml = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
objxml.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
objXML.async =  False
objXML.Load url
```

Then it traverses the XML, inserts the data into a DB and then finishes. The outcome of this is around 40MB of files in this location every hour:

```
C:\Users\[theUser]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE
```

As I said above. I have logged into the server as [theUser] and set the upper limit to 200MB but it does not obey this. How can I stop this process blowing out the temp Internet files location for [theUser]?

Edited: The accepted solution is better if you are not behind a proxy IMO. I elected to run the WST with high prvelleges and do this:

```
 call dumpAllFilesInFolder("C:\Users\[theUser]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE")
 function dumpAllFilesInFolder(theFullPath)
    dim objFS, curFile, objFolder, objFiles
    Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(theFullPath) 
    Set objFiles = objFolder.Files
    For each curFile in objFiles
        objFS.DeleteFile(curFile)
    Next
end function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless otherwise specified DOMDocument uses WinINET API which was developed for user interactive applications primarily. The cache files that cause the problem you are experiencing are created due to [WinINET's cache behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/caching), in short: everything that can be cached must be cached.

As an alternative you can force your `DomDocument` object to use WinHTTP by setting `ServerHTTPRequest` property to `True`. Unlike WinINET, WinHTTP was designed for server-side applications, so nothing will be cached. Seems better for your environment.

```vb
Set objxml = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
objxml.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
objxml.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
objXML.async = False
objXML.Load url
```

---

**Related Links**

- [ServerHTTPRequest Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms766434(v%3Dvs.85))
- [WinINet vs. WinHTTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/wininet-vs-winhttp)

Comment: thank you I will try this now and see if ti stops the dir filling up.  Its seems like a perfect solution if it works. Thank you for your time ans advice!

Comment: After checking the script closer it would appear that this fails with the following XML parse error when behind a proxy.  ERROR : XML ParseError occured : System error: -2147012889.

Comment: @Mat41 Take a look at `Remarks` section at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms766434(v%3Dvs.85)#remarks search for `Intranet` on the page.

Comment: thank you. I have been reading this, a proxycfg.exe utility is required because of my environment. I elected to run the script with higher privileges instead of configuring proxycfg.  Now I simply use FSO to connect and dump the temp internet files dir. this is working well. Your solution still deserves to be upheld because its a great one if no proxy.  Thanking you